# How to get the IDs/titles of every item in a shopify store

Tags: python, json, shopify

I am trying to get the variant IDs (variant because each item has different sizes) and public_titles of every single item in a Shopify store. I can get the variants/titles of a single item by using the following code I wrote:

```
r = session.get(url)
html = r.text
JSON = re.compile('var meta = ({.*?});', re.DOTALL)
matches = JSON.search(html)
shopifydata = json.loads(matches.group(1))
for variant in shopifydata['product']['variants']:
    variants.append(variant['id'])
    raw_sizes.append(variant['public_title'])
```

But I'd like to know if it is possible to make an array of every item in the shop, even if the item is not yet visible? I am not Admin on this store.

Comment: You'll probably get your answer in the Shopify API's documentation... Did you check there?

Comment: @edouardtheron I tried /admin/inventory_items.json but it prompts a username and password. I was wondering if it was possible to do without being admin.

Comment: @edouardtheron {"errors":"[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)"}

Comment: From what I see on the API doc (https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/product) there is a `published_at` field that is returned by the API call, which probably means that only published products can get fetched...

Comment: @edouardtheron Okay but I'm looking for a way to do this as a non-admin anyway, I don't mind if it shows published items only